# databinding datagrid's comboboxes and textboxes to staticresource list

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've created a WPF vb.net form containing datagrid. Inside of datagrid I have two comboboxes and two textboxes, one combobox textbox pair for articles and another one for services. I should bind first combo to property of List(Of article) type and second to List(Of service) type where article is public class containing two public properties (articleId and articleName) and service is public class containing two public properties (serviseId and serviceName). Textboxes should display article and service names and comboboxes should display IDs. When combo selection is changed textbox text should change its value too.

List(Of article) and List(Of service) should be populated from database.

How could I do this, I know that solution is somewhere around me but can't catch it at all. There are two main problems, binding controls and populatin list from database.

If I need to post a part of code I'm gonna do this, just let me know.

Please help me to solve this situation,

thanks.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Hi lena, please let me know how to post code.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand what are you trying to do. Why do you need a DataGrid? You want number of rows to be equal to number of rows in your Table's Rows?

Comment: By the way, if you need to add some code to your question, you better edit it instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: I want to display to user what of articles is responding for using. The same thing is with services. I think the best way to do this is presenting data in form of table (using datagrid). If user has finished populating datagrid data should go to database creating one row in third table (not articles nor services) called package.

Comment: Maybe if you draw some kind of scheme - how you want it to look, it would be easier to describe it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - sorry, I am not very familiar with VB.Net, so my code is written in c#. Since I have no understanding of what you actually need, I can only offer you a following not really elegant solution.

For binding your `ComboBox` to the items from database you need to use a `StaticResource`, as I can see you did it, but maybe you defined it wrong, that's why it is not working for you. To get it work you need to have a class like this:

```
public class artiklsList : List<artikl>
{
    public artiklsList()
    {
        this.Add(new artikl(1, "first")); //this is dummy items, you need to do a database stuff here
        this.Add(new artikl(2, "second"));
        this.Add(new artikl(3, "third"));
    }
}
```

And a xaml like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:artiklsList x:Key="source"></my:artiklsList>
</Window.Resources>
```

You also need update a cell with text when a `ComboBox` selection changed. It's not a simple task, because the easiest way to do this using `Binding` to the control using `ElementName` will not work in the `DataGrid`. What I did is kinda hacky anyway...

So, xaml is not very complicated:

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgrStavke" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="160" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Artikl ID">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding selectedIndexID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Name="cmbArtikli" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="artiklId" ItemsSource="{StaticResource source}">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naziv artikla"  Binding="{Binding nazivArtikla}"/>          
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The binding of `SelectedIndex` and a horrible code-behind doing the trick with updating a text cell. For binding to work properly `articl` class have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
public class artikl: INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public artikl(int artid, string nazivart)
    {
        artiklId = artid;
        nazivArtikla = nazivart;
    }

    public int artiklId{get;set;}

    private string _nazv;
    public string nazivArtikla
    {
        get { return _nazv; }
        set { _nazv = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("nazivArtikla"); }
    }

    //Here I think you may have questions
    private int _index;
    public int selectedIndexID 
    {
        get 
        {
            //To get a SelectedIndex for ComboBox in current row we look in 
            //listArtikli defined in a MainWindow for a articli item with a current 
            //item's Id and take the index of this item
            artikl art = MainWindow.listArtikli.Find(el => el.artiklId == this.artiklId);
            return MainWindow.listArtikli.IndexOf(art);
        } 
        set 
        {
            //This property is binded with SelectedIndex property of ComboBox.
            //When selected index changed, we look in listArtikli and take 
            //here properties of item with this index.
            //This will change values of item binded to the current grid row
            _index = value;
            this.nazivArtikla = MainWindow.listArtikli[value].nazivArtikla;
            this.artiklId = MainWindow.listArtikli[value].artiklId;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("selectedIndexID");
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And a window code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static artiklsList listArtikli = new artiklsList();
    public static artiklsList gridsource = new artiklsList();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgrStavke.ItemsSource = gridsource;
    }
}
```

You need `gridsource` aside from `listArtikli` to fill your `DataGrid` with values. Also because of all this code in `selectedIndexID` if you use only `listArtikli` its values corrupting. So `listArtikli` contains `articli` items just sorted in order which they were retrieved. And `gridsource` contains pairs `artiklId`-`nazivArtikla` as they presented in the `DataGrid`.
Hope it will help you just a little.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for interesting. If you need more clarification please let me know. This is the code for one pair combobox-textbox, I'll easily apply this for another one:
XAML
...

```
<DataGrid Name="dgrStavke" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="160" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Artikl ID">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Name="cmbArtikli" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource artcls}, Path=listArtikli}" DisplayMemberPath="artiklId"></ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naziv artikla" Binding="{Binding nazivArtikla}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

...

CODE

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Namespace MW

    Public Class artikl

        Sub New(artid As Integer, nazivart As String)
            ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
            artiklId = artid
            nazivArtikla = nazivart
        End Sub

        Public Property artiklId() As Integer
        Public Property nazivArtikla() As String
    End Class

    Public Class frmDodavanjePaketa
    Public Property listArtikli() As New List(Of artikl)

    Private Sub popuniComboArtikli()
            Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(moduleGlobal.connString)
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim strSql As New StringBuilder
            strSql.Append("select a.artiklId, a.nazivArtikla ")
            strSql.Append(" from artikli a ")
            strSql.Append(" where isnull(a.aktivan, 0) = 1")

            Dim sqlCom As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSql.ToString, sqlConn)
            Dim sqlDs As DataSet = New DataSet
            Dim sqlDa As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
            sqlDa.SelectCommand = sqlCom
            sqlDa.Fill(sqlDs)

            For Each row As DataRow In sqlDs.Tables(0).Rows
                Me.listArtikli.Add(New artikl(row.ItemArray(0).ToString, row.ItemArray(1).ToString))
            Next

        End Sub
      End Class
      End Namespace
```